# Event handler in object literal not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am creating a Wordpress plugin and I have created an object literal in which I would like to encapsulate all my logic, but I can't seem to get the event handler to fire.

I am using jQuery 1.7.1

First, I have rows of data that is being created via php:

```
<div class="table-wrapper">

    <?php 
        global $wpdb;

        $students = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT studentID, lname, fname, email FROM student");    

  foreach($students as $student) : ?>
    <div class="row" id="<?php echo $student->studentID; ?>" >
        <div class="last_name">
            <h4><?php echo __($student->lname); ?></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="first_name">
            <h4><?php echo __($student->fname); ?></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="phone">
            <h4><?php echo __($student->phone); ?></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="email">
            <h4><?php echo __($student->email); ?></h4>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /row -->
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <div id="new">
        <button id="new_student"><?php echo __('Add New Student'); ?></button>
    </div>
</div><!-- /table-wrapper -->
```

And this is my javascript/jquery file:

```
var Student = {
  init: function(config) {
    this.config = config;
    this.isDisplayed = false;
    console.log('in init');  // this fires upon instantiation
    this.bindEvents();
  },

  bindEvents: function(){
    console.log('in bind');  // this fires upon instantiation
    this.config.studentSelection.on('click', '.row', this.config.fetchStudentDetails);
    console.log('after');  // this does NOT fire

  },

  fetchStudentDetails: function() {
    var self = Student;
    alert('in event');   // this does NOT fire
  }
};

Student.init({
  studentID: jQuery('.row').attr('id'),
  studentSelection: jQuery('.table-wrapper')
});
```

I have tried a couple of small variations such as passing in the '.row' to the studentSelection variable and just trying to tie the event handler to it directly in the bindEvents method:

```
bindEvents: function(){
    console.log('in bind');  // this fires upon instantiation
    this.config.studentSelection.on('click', this.config.fetchStudentDetails);
    console.log('after');  // this does NOT fire
  },

Student.init({
  studentID: jQuery('.row').attr('id'),
  studentSelection: jQuery('.row')
});
```

I am, however, able to fire the click event when I write out the code like this:

```
jQuery('.row').click, function(){
     console.log('in click event');
});
```

I don't understand what is happening, so if anyone can shed some light on it or point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Shouldn't `this.config.fetchStudentDetails` be `this.fetchStudentDetails`?

Comment: Thank you for answering so quickly Paolo.  That actually doesn't work either, I have also tried calling it by using Student.fetchStudentDetails, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Your `this` context is all wrong. `this.config.studentSelection` is `undefined` as well as `this.config.fetchStudentDetails`. The `this` refers to `bindEvents` not to `init`. I suggest you use a different pattern here. Something like this:

```
var Student = function (config) {

    config = config || {};

    var that = this, // In case you need to use the original `this`
        isDisplayed = false;

    var init = function () {
        console.log('in init');
        bindEvents();
    };

    var bindEvents = function () {
        console.log('in bind');
        config.studentSelection.on('click', '.row', fetchStudentDetails);
        console.log('after');
    };

    var fetchStudentDetails = function () {
        // var self = Student; <-- Use `that`
        alert('in event');
    };

    return {
        init: init,
        bindEvents: bindEvents,
        fetchStudentDetails: fetchStudentDetails
    }

};

// Create a new student
var student = new Student({ ... });
student.init();
```

Comment: thank you for responding.  I wish I could say that I understand everything but as I am still trying to wrap my head around the object literal notation and this pattern I don't yet see the benefit/difference between the two.  I have tried your code as well and it still doesn't work, I never see the `console.log('after')` statement in bindEvents fire, which leads me to believe that there is something wrong the `config.studentSelection.on('click', '.row', fetchStudentDetails)` statement, the code just seems to stop there.